# How to fix "Oops! Something went wrong." error using locationmap module in Drupal?

Tags: drupal-7

I followed the following tutorial to include 'locationmap' module in my Drupal website.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7oQXBaG5Xpw

I am able to add the module and view map block but I get the below error.[Oops Something went wrong error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qBCH.png)

Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you check the console and see if your are getting errors

Comment: Yes. I am getting a key-map error. 

Error : "Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error"

I understand that it is asking me to enter API Key but I am not sure where can I put it when I use 'locationmap' module as I was not able to find any field where I can input the same.

Comment: <script async defer
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY">
    </script>

for more options refer the documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial